# How to remove key-value pairs from a dictionary where the key matches an item in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
my_dict = {'i': 5, 'citizens': 12, 'you': 344, 'the': 567, 'me': 11, 'states': 22, '': 104, 'in': 156}
```

and a list that looks like

```
ignore_words = ['i', 'we', 'you', 'he', 'she', 'it', 'they', 'me', 'us']
```

I would like to edit the dictionary to remove all the key-value pairs where one of the keys matches an item in the list so I have output that looks like:

```
my_dict = {'citizens': 12, 'the': 567, 'states': 22, '': 104, 'in': 156}
```

I've tried

```
[my_dict.pop(key) for key in ignore_words]
```

but I get a `KeyError`.
What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) on [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) with `ignore_list`

```
keys = my_dict.keys() - ignore_words
out  = {k: my_dict[k] for k in keys}
# {'': 104, 'in': 156, 'states': 22, 'citizens': 12, 'the': 567}
```